# Dynamic Variables and javascript loops and checks

Tags: javascript, variables, loops, dynamic

i have the following problem:
I'm creating this check for my website but I can't make it work. I have a series of variables created with PHP that take information from my database. Every variable has a specific value in it, it is a name, lets say "example 1". the variables create automatically so if there are 10 voices in the database, then i will have "example 1", "example 2", and so on... each one of these inside a variable named test_1, test_2...
The problem comes in javascript when i need to check the selected value in a dropdown list. According to the value selected, the next dropdown changes accordingly. 
let me put some code in it:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('bla');
var lengthtot = vartot.length;
for(var a = 0; a<lengthtot; a++){       
    if(elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value == test_[a]){
        alert("it works");
```

the problem is the "== test_[a]". I can't make it work, i've tried [a],+a,.a,$a. I want something like PHP `bla_$i = ${'ble_'.$i`}

I've been looking everywhere for an answer but still haven't found it yet. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to do it with the object as you said, but i had to do it from php to make it work automatically, here is the code i wrote, i tested it so there is no problem with it:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <?php
        echo "var test125 = {\n";           
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $mycounterlength; $i++){             
        echo "$i: {\n";
        echo "value: ${'bla_'.$i},\n";
        echo "func: ${'ble_'.$i}\n";
        echo "},\n";
        }
    echo "}\n";
?>
</script>
```

Anyway, thanks for the suggestion again, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate an object instead of multiple variables.

```
var tests = {
    1: 'value of your previous test_1 variable',
    ...
}
```

And in your code :

```
if (elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value === tests[a]) {
```

Comment: i need the multiple variables because each variable is connected to another functions and each function does something different

Comment: If you really need a different function for each of your var, you can use it directly inside the object : http://jsfiddle.net/jpZb7/

Comment: I'm trying to use your method but how can i assign automatically the values and the function to the object? i mean:
1:{
value: test_[a]
fn: func_[a]
you see, it is always the same problem, since the variables and functions change accordingly to the database, i need it to do it automatically

Comment: "functions change accordingly to the database" I'm not sure I understand this correctly. Does the code of the function come directy from your PHP call ? Or do you call different client function given a value returned by your PHP ?

Comment: functions generate automatically from php and then exported into javascript to be used. what i mean is that the parameters of each function change into the php according to the database used. anyway, i've been studying objects since you mention them and i think i found the solution using php objects and then exporting them into javascript. i will post the code as soon as i finish working on it to show you what i meant. anyway, your suggestion was key for me to discover that new area of programming and i thank you for that, though was not the solution i was hoping for.